# Find $f$ such that $\int^b_a f^2(x) = c$ and $\int^b_a f(x)g(x) dx$ should be maximum

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Given $g$ integrable on $[a,b]$, find integrable $f$ such that $\int^b_a  f^2(x) = c > 0$ and $\int^b_a f(x)g(x) dx$ should be maximum.

I tried to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and define $d:= \int^b_a g^2(x)dx $ and

$$|\int^b_a f(x)g(x) dx  | \leq \int^b_a |f(x)g(x)| dx  \leq ( \int^b_a  g^2(x) \int^b_a  f^2(x))^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{cd} ,$$

so if $f(x)=\frac{c}{d}g(x)$ all the inequalities are equalities and we get the maximum.

I'm not sure if this the right answer (for $d =0$ it's trival). Thank you.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to maximize, and what are your assumptions - I don't quite get that

Comment: the assumption are g(x) integrable on [a,b] the problem is to find f(x) integrable that has two conditions. 
1. $\int^b_af^2(x)dx=c>0$
2. maximize $\int^b_af(x)g(x)dx$

Comment: You are maximising a linear function on the boundary of the $c$ ball. That should suggest a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b fg$, then Cauchy Schwarz gives
$\langle f,g \rangle \le \|f\| \|g\|$, so you know that
$\langle f,g \rangle \le \sqrt{c} \sqrt{d}$.

If you choose $f= {\sqrt{c} \over \sqrt{d}} g$, then you have equality.